Is it okay to ignore missing data despite a very small percentage?
My dataset has seven cols and 63 mil rows. There are two columns with missing data. The first one [Terminal Number] has 400k rows of missing data but thankfully, I can extract values from another column [Order Number] to get that data. The Order Number column is formatted like 9***|5****|4*********. The Terminal Number column just contains the first two elements if you split the Order Number by '|'.So that's solved. Now the other column with missing data is the [Date/Time] Column. Only 60 rows are missing data. Is it okay to ignore it? I mean the percentage is so small.

What do you want to do with the data? Whether it is ok or not depends a bit on that task (but also on the data)

If you lose 60 data out of a total of 63,000 it is not significant, it is only 0.095% of the data. You can negotiate that with your counterpart in the business.
Now, keep in mind what the business is asking for, if it's a statistical measure like averages or regressions it doesn't seem significant. On the other hand, if you use this for more exact measures such as cumulative values, totals, goals, it may be advisable to put a default value that fits with the business reports.
